# Remove docker image which has dependent children images

Tags: docker, docker-image

I want remove docker images, but I meet error message like this:

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 47bcc53f74dc
>   (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

I stop all containers by `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` command. After that, I remove all **busybox** images by `docker rmi $(docker images | grep "busybox" | awk '{print $3}')` command. And I meet error message like above.

I show `docker images | grep busybox` and get information like below:

```
busybox             1                   47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             1-uclibc            47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             1.24                47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             1.24-uclibc         47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             1.24.2              47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             1.24.2-uclibc       47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
busybox             uclibc              47bcc53f74dc        6 months ago        1.113 MB
```

How can I remove **busybox** images? Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 2):

The warning suggests you that some of the containers still linked (inherit) docker FS layers of ones you're going to delete. There is no option to delete intermediate docker filesystem layers without recreating child images based on those.

Say, you've got configuration like:

```
base_layer_A -> base_layer_B
           \        \_ child_layer_D
            \__ container C
```

... willing to delete container C and layer A.

You cannot do so (because layer B is based on layer A). That's the most likely reason of your problem

PS: `docker images -a` might shed some light to you (unlikely). There was a '-tree' switch once to help with such case, but it's gone now, unfortunately

---

Here is a straight and brute way to clean up abandoned docker containers and deprecated image layers

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

for c in $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -f status=created -f status=dead --format="{{.ID}}"); do
    docker rm $c
done
for img in $(docker images -f dangling=true --format="{{.ID}}"); do
    docker rmi $img
done
```

Comment: Oh, I tried your command. Are there solutions find relative images and manual delete them? Thanks

Comment: There are trivial ways to remove image layers not related to anything (simply done with few commands matching 'none' tags).
As for displaying docker image layers tree - there was a command to render such (the '--tree', as I've mentioned), which was removed, nothing like that I'm aware about, unfortunately. Wish to now smth. like it myself

Comment: You can start analyzing docker container running / enabled (with docker ps __-a__, killing ones / going down the tree then

Comment: your commands do delete orphaned layers, but it doesn't solve the problem (rmi -f still returns failure due to dependent images)